# Python - second smallest number with user input

Tags: python

I found a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IuHTPffYMoM) with a program to find the second smallest number in a list. I am trying to modify this code so it works with user input. This is the code from the video:

```
numbers = [ 6, 6, 6, 4, 3, 4, 5 ]

print(f"Number: {numbers}")

first = 10000 
second = 10000

for number in numbers:
    if number < first:
        second = first
        first = number
    elif number > first and number < second:
        second = number

print(f"First:  {first}")
print(f"Second: {second}")
```

And this is what I have so far but the output is always 99 and I can't figure out how to solve it. (I work with python 2.7)

```
list = str(raw_input())

first = 99
second = 99

for number in list:
    if number < first:
        second = first
        first = number
    elif first < number < second:
        second = number

print "The second smallest number is : %d" % second
```

I know there are already some questions about this topic but they all work with functions and I don't know how to use them yet.

Comment: `str()` returns a string, not a list.

Comment: `raw_input()` returns a string, you don't need to call `str()`.

Comment: also probably don't call the variable `list` since that's a python type already..

Comment: What is your user input like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str()` and `raw_input()` return strings, not lists. If you want to get a list of the words the user typed, you need to use `split()`. And then you need to convert them to integers with `int()`.

Also, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name, since it's the name of a built-in function.

```
number_list = map(int, raw_input().split())
for number in number_list:
    ...
```

Comment: In case @Ellie Doesn't know `.split()` takes a singular string and sends it to a list of items where each item is the letters broken by spaces. I.e. `"1 2 3 4".split()` would output `["1", "2", "3", "4"]`.  Map then casts each of these items to an int.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `raw_input()` returns a string, not a list. So, you need to split your string into multiple parts (each part being one of the numbers) in order to get a list from your input.

Assuming your input is of the following form (i.e. the numbers separated by commas):

```
input = '1,2,3,4,5,6'
```

You can split this string by the comma character to get a list like so:

```
input_list_strings = input.split(',')
#input_list_strings = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

Then you need to convert the character list to integers

```
input_list = [int(string) for string in input_list_strings]
#input_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

You could do all this in one line with:

```
input_list = [int(string) for string in input.split(',')]
```

Then you should be able to continue with your algorithm normally.

The stuff in the brackets is called a list comprehension, it's generally considered more pythonic to use a list comprehension than it is to use `map` because it's more readable. You can read about them [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python).

Comment: The answer seems to be similar to the other and although useful do not add anything else.

Comment: @FranciscoMelojunior I was writing my answer when Barmar posted his. You're talking as if I literally copy/pasted his answer.

Comment: No, just justifying why I downvoted your answer and how you can improve, most of the people only downvote.

Comment: @FranciscoMelojunior There will inevitably be similar answers to a question like this. There is only one answer to give. Downvoting people because they have taken the time to write an answer (at the same time as the other answer) is A: inane and B: disincentivizes thoughtful (slow) answers. Furthermore, this is clearly a better answer, because invoking `map` for an early user seems like a poor choice. Better to use a list comprehension (which I will edit this to use).